# What is the certificate store where my USB Token is listed? (Crypto API)

Tags: delphi, cryptoapi

I'm trying to show the default dialog box to select certificate listing my USB token (G&D Burti StarSign). I can show this dialog listing all installed certificates, but my token is not shown. How can I do it using CAPI? (An exemple would be great!)

PS.: The programming language is Delphi, but I understand another C like (C++/C#) languages

The software for token administration show my token:
[image]

Comment: You can try to spy on that "working" application by some WinAPI monitor (e.g. [this one](https://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)). If you're lucky (and you might be, because crypto API is defined by Crypt32.xml definition file), you will see which functions are called and how.

Comment: Hello @Victoria. That's an interesting approach! I will try this also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The CSP / drivers need to propagate the certificate to your local machine. Verify the certificate is visible using the certificate mmc snapin. Once you know the certificate store being used, used the above mentioned CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore to view them.

Comment: Hi @Greg! Thanks for the answer, but the certificate inside my token do not apear on any store listed on the certificate mmc snapin. It appears only on the SafeSign software (See the image on the question, above)

Comment: Their software may not use the local CAPI cert stores then. I'd suggest trying to get their SDK or talk to the support people for that token.

Comment: Thank you @Greg. I'll do this